# Why is 32 bit version of Ubuntu the recommended download on Ubuntu.com?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32-vs-64-bit

I was wondering if there is any reason why 32 bit would be recommended for download on the Ubuntu.com site. My Macbook Pro 7,1 has a 64 bit processor; I'm wondering whether the support for 64 bit applications on ubuntu isn't good enough yet, and maybe its still not stable enough, or just that its recommended because most people installing Ubuntu will be doing so on 32 bit machines, and they are trying to make it easier.

I've already looked at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/128479/ubuntu-64-or-32-bit-for-macbook-vps) question on Superuser and it doesn't answer this question, so I don't think this is a repeat.

Thanks

Comment: One reason: Drivers

Comment: same question on [ubuntu.se] - [Why does Ubuntu Download recommend 32-bit install?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1441/1182)

Comment: this question is an exact duplicate from askubuntu.stackexchange.com: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-does-ubuntu-download-recommend-32-bit-install (IMO the askubuntu question is more fleshed out and more thoroughly peer reviewed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote Marco Ceppi from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1445/34265):

> This is actually just a mis-wording of sorts. According to LaunchPad Bug #585940 It's meant to convey that typical desktops are 32-bit whereas more recent desktops are 64-bit. Since the 32bit install will always work on both 32bit and 64bit machines it remains "recommended"

Answer (score 0):

32 bit is compatible with both systems. 
Another example: some sound libraries in java won't work on 64 bit system with 64 bit ubuntu installed.

Comment: "some sound libraries in java won't work on 64 bit system with 64 bit ubuntu installed" - does that mean that they don't work on 64 bit PROCESSORS or just 64 bit ubuntu? Also, isn't that a little obscure, or are these libraries very used?

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  The sound libraries were not compiled to support a 64-bit installation of Ubuntu.  They likely were not compiled to support any 64-bit linux operating system.